# Vector orthogonalisation that keeps (as many as possible) zero elements

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have a matrix $\bf{A}$ of orthonormal vectors (columns of that matrix). Most of these vectors have some elements which have a numerical value close to zero. For every column of $\bf{A}$, I go through all elements and whenever the element is smaller than a threshold $\alpha$, I set it to zero. Usually, after this process about 10% of elements get zeroed and of course the vectors are no longer orthonormal.

Is there a method that I could use to re-normalize and re-orthogonalise the columns, but one that promotes keeping many* of the set-to-zero elements still equal to zero?

For now I only re-normalize every column dividing by its norm and I tried Gram-Schmidt orthogonalisation with [this algorithm](http://web.mit.edu/18.06/www/Essays/gramschmidtmat.pdf). It seems to maintain the zero elements only in the first vector. 
This is a good start, as *in fact, it is most important for me if the set-to-zero elements are maintained only in about first 50% of the columns. I wonder if I can do better using a different technique.

Comment: My approach here would be to set all the subthreshold values to zero, then "reorthogonalize and renormalize" by solving the [orthogonal procrustes problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_Procrustes_problem)
$$
R = \arg \min_{\Omega} \|\Omega - \mathbf A\|_F \qquad \text{s.t. } \Omega^T \Omega = I
$$
which would make the zero values non-zero again, but would bring you closer.
I suspect that iterating this process would get you an orthogonal matrix where the sub-threshold entries are made as close to zero as possible